# XCode and svn client certificates

Tags: xcode, svn

I've been stuck on an error in Xcode for over a year:
"The server “my.servername.net” requires a client certificate."
I have svn client certificates correctly setup on my Mac and can properly access our internal svn via the command line. I can also browse it via Safari. For whatever reason, I cannot access it through Xcode.  Irecall some years ago discovering how Xcode uses its own svn client. I'm not sure if that means it may/may-not honor local ~/.subversion/servers settings. In my case I have my servers file correctly identifying my client certificate but it just doesn't work. Help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 4 SVN hanging at “Checking out” if client certificate required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987676/xcode-4-svn-hanging-at-checking-out-if-client-certificate-required/17436090#17436090) or of your very own [Point XCode4 to my client certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463781/point-xcode4-to-my-client-certificate)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer with the help of a buddy. I never imported my ".pem" certificate into keychain. Things seem to work differently after the import.